# How do I import a remote module, that imports a local module?

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

I have my program importing a module from a different location using `importlib`.
 This imported module (let's call it **A**) imports some other custom module located next to it (let's call it **B**).

```
My_Project\
    │
    └─── my_program.py

Some_Other_Location\
    │
    ├─── A_module_my_program_wants_to_import.py
    └─── B_module_A_imports.py
```

When I import **A** *without* it importing **B**, it works just fine:

```
# Sample from my_program.py

path = Some_Other_Location\A_module_my_program_wants_to_import.py
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("A", path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

However, when in **A** I import **B**:

```
# Sample from A_module_my_program_wants_to_import.py

import B_module_A_imports
```

Or

```
from B_module_A_imports import foo
```

And I run my program, I get:

> `Build error: No module named 'B_module_A_imports'` 
>   And a traceback to where I import in my program, and **A**

I've tried specifying `submodule_search_locations=Some_Other_Location` of `spec_from_file_location` but it didn't help.

So the question is **how do I import a remote module, that imports a local module?**

Comment: It seems circular import to me, is this the case?

Comment: It is not. This is the import order: my_program -> **A** -> **B**. Neighter **A** or **B** has anything to do with my_program, and **B** is independent from **A**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround, not a proper solution though. The workaround is as follows:

I've realised that it's trying to load **B** where my_program is located and obviously didn't find anything. However, it is possible to trick the loader to find the file, by adding `Some_Other_Location` to `sys.path`. So this is what the import part of my_program looks like:

```
directory = Some_Other_Location
sys.path.append(directory)

path = Some_Other_Location\A_module_my_program_wants_to_import.py
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("A", path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

sys.path.remove(directory)
```

This works just fine, however, I'm still open for actual solutions!